# Flutter navigation bar

Tags: dart, flutter

I just started app developing and im struggling with navigation bar. The bottom one is good but the one at the top is not. I want to remove the grey space above the buttons.

Can you help me?

[image]

Code:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {   
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      bottom: new TabBar(
        controller: controller,
        tabs: <Tab>[
          new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)),
          new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_downward)),
          new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
        ]
      )
    ),        
    body: new TabBarView(
      controller: controller,
      children: <Widget>[
        new first.First(),
        new second.Second(),
        new third.Third(),
        new fourth.Fourth(),
        new fifth.Fifth()
      ]
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't use `Appbar` then. Use a `Card` with an elevation of 26.0. As what you want is a custom appbar:

```
final tab = new TabBar(tabs: <Tab>[
  new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)),
  new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_downward)),
  new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
]);
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: tab.preferredSize,
    child: new Card(
      elevation: 26.0,
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      child: tab,
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

To update this question,
It's much easier for me to use
`DefaultTabController` with `AppBar` and `TabBarView`.

For example,

```
final upperTab = const TabBar(tabs: <Tab>[
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward)),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
  ]);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: upperTab,
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.flight, size: 350),
            Icon(Icons.directions_transit, size: 350),
            Icon(Icons.directions_car, size: 350),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```